# Package manager error every time I create a project

Tags: unity-container

Package manager error every time I create a new project in Unity
occurs. I'm removing the error from the package manager, but it's inconvenient to get the error every time I create a project. How can I resolve this?

I'm removing the error from the package manager, but it's inconvenient to get the error every time I create a project.

Comment: Could you post the specific error message the you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try using VPN when you create a new project
- If the problem is not solved, install an LTS version of Unity

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory of your project and delete the library and package folder then reopen the project.